# How to get iterating prefixes to row names in sublists with rapply?

Tags: r, apply

I know how to add a string to row names of a list with `rapply`.

```
out1 <- rapply(L, function(x) 
  `rownames<-`(x, paste0("lala.", rownames(x))), how="list")

out1$a$ct
#        x1 x2 x3
# lala.a  1  1  1
# lala.b  1  1  1
```

How could this be done if I want to iterate the string depending on the sublist's name?

In `lapply` situations I would iterate along the sequences with `lapply(seq_along(L)`, but I'm not sure if this works with `rapply`. E.g.

```
out2 <- rapply(seq_along(L), function(x) names(L)[x], how="list")
```

won't work, and it yields

```
Error in rapply(seq(L), function(x) names(L[[x]]), how = "list") : 
  'object' must be a list or expression
```

Maybe I need another `*apply` e.g. `mapply`?

***Edits:*** I wonder if this could be done within a single base function call from the `*apply` family.

I also tried `outer`

```
outer(seq(L$a),seq(L$b), Vectorize(function(x, y) 
  `rownames<-`(L[[x]][[y]], paste0(names(L[[x]])[y], ".", rownames(L[[x]][[y]])))))
```

which failed into:

```
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 4] do not match the length of object [24]
```

while

```
x <- 1; y <- 2
`rownames<-`(L[[x]][[y]], paste0(names(L[[x]])[y], ".", rownames(L[[x]][[y]])))
#      x1 x2 x3
# tr.a  1  1  1
# tr.b  1  1  1
```

***Expected output***

```
# $a
# $a$ct
# x1 x2 x3
# ct.a  1  1  1
# ct.b  1  1  1
# 
# $a$tr
# x1 x2 x3
# tr.a  1  1  1
# tr.b  1  1  1
# 
# 
# $b
# $b$ct
# x1 x2 x3
# ct.a  1  1  1
# ct.b  1  1  1
# 
# $b$tr
# x1 x2 x3
# tr.a  1  1  1
# tr.b  1  1  1
```

***Data***

```
L <- list(a = list(ct = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "b"), c("x1", "x2", "x3"))), tr = structure(c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("x1", 
"x2", "x3")))), b = list(ct = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "b"), c("x1", "x2", "x3"))), tr = structure(c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = 2:3, .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b"), c("x1", 
"x2", "x3")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but you could use Map/mapply to iterate over your data.frames and their names and use lapply for your second order list structure.

```
addString2RowName <- function(df, string) {
  row.names(df) <- paste(string, rownames(df), sep = ".")
  df
}

lapply(L, function(l) Map(addString2RowName, df = l, string = names(l)))
```

Comment: I like your solution, however, I wonder if  this could be done with a single function call from the `*apply` family.

Comment: To my understanding you have a double nested list structure (data.frames nested in lists nested in a list) and you will need two loops (or apply family calls) to iterate over them.

Comment: For double `lapply` we indeed can often do `rapply`, but I can't get it to work in my case; or the `outer` in my edit.

Comment: I really don't see a way of doing this. You could use
`lapply(names(L$a), function(nam) {
  row.names(L$a[[nam]]) <- paste(nam, rownames(L$a[[nam]]), sep = ".")
  L$a[[nam]]
})` 
to use `lapply` within a single list (instead of `Map`, but then you are using the list elements name and not the list itself (which makes it to my understanding impossible to use it in `rapply`).